# Is it possible to obfuscate a single Powershell line?

Tags: powershell

In javascript, you can use something like eval(function{p,a,c,k,e,d ... to obfusicate code. Is it possible to do that with a **single line** of Powershell.

Basically, I load in a Powershell file, and it check the order of a string. If it is "A|B|C" it changes the code to "B|C|A". When the browser starts, if it sees "B|C|A" in that JS file, and it runs.  When the browser exits, Powershell changes it back to "A|B|C" again (If the user now tries to open the HTML page directly, Javascript sees "A|B|C" in the file, - incorrect code - and exits the app)

Obviously, if the user see's what's happening, they will now how do defeat the lock. So I want to 'hide' either the source of the file, or the processing operation. Here then is the code:

```
 $obsData = Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 "$ScriptDir\ob_data.js"
 if ($obsData -like 'maxlength|run|outfile'){
      $obsData[1] -replace 'norun','-r-' -replace 'run','norun' -replace '-r-','run'|Out-File  -Encoding UTF8 "$myPath\ob_data.js"
      Start-Process $browserChoice "file:$ScriptDir/standard.html" -WindowStyle Maximized
 }
```

The reverse happens on exit, changing the position of 'run' and 'norun' (By the way, the 'maxlength|run|outfile' string shown is at the end of an eval obfusicated JS code)

I'm not looking for 'heavy duty' malware style obfusication using SecureString etc, just something that will put the "average user" off the scent ... such as

```
 "ob_data.js"
 -Encoding UTF8 "$ScriptDir\char[6f] char[62] char[5f] chat[64]...
 $file= (base64 to ASCII)="b2JfZGF0YS5qcw=="
 -Encoding UTF8 "$ScriptDir\$file
```

If it could 'hide' the replace line with even more cryptic code - again so the average person can't suss what's happening, even better.

In practice, the script changes the position of "run" and norun" So default is (run="0" norun="1") When swapped by Powershell (norun="0" run="1") without affecting the obfusicated code.

Comment: What you are saying you want is not obfuscation, it's a simple string array rotation. So, you are saying through your doing this rotation, you don't want that part to be human-readable? All that notwithstanding, you cannot ru nPowerShell commands/code form a public facing or interal web page. Internall you can use HTA's to run PowerShell stuff, but most well-managed orgs block HTA's as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike JavaScript, you cannot run PowerShell commands/code from a browser.

> [Web Page to Run PowerShell Scripts](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c789e0c4-618f-463f-8fcb-886a7b003380/web-page-to-run-powershell-scripts)
>
> You can't run it directly from any webpage.  You need some sort of web
> app wrapper to kick it off.  ...
>
> C# wrapper Code:

```
private List<PSObject> RunPowershellScript(string relativePath, List<CommandParameter> parameters)
        {
            using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
            {

                RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
                Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
                runspace.Open();
                RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
                Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                //Here's how you add a new script with arguments
                Command cmd = new Command(Server.MapPath(relativePath));
                
                foreach (var item in parameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(item);
                }
                
                pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);
                // Execute PowerShell script
                var res = pipeline.Invoke();
                var results =res.ToList();
                return results;
            }
        }
```

Or leveraging [this approach](http://devinfra-us.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-powershell-20-from-aspnet-part-1.html):

You can base encode any string or command using PowerShell.

[Simple Obfuscation with PowerShell using Base64 Encoding](https://mikefrobbins.com/2017/06/15/simple-obfuscation-with-powershell-using-base64-encoding)

```
powershell.exe /?

# The help for PowerShell.exe also shows you how to encode a command with Base64:
[Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("'mikefrobbins.com'"))

# While it could be decoded within PowerShell:
[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String('JwBtAGkAawBlAGYAcgBvAGIAYgBpAG4AcwAuAGMAbwBtACcA'))

<#
Adding quotes around the domain name also allows it to be decoded with 
PowerShell.exe using the -EncodedCommand parameter without having to encode it 
with a command such as Write-Output:
#>

powershell.exe -encodedCommand JwBtAGkAawBlAGYAcgBvAGIAYgBpAG4AcwAuAGMAbwBtACcA
```

However, a properly risk-managed network will block this encoded stuff because this is how hackers operate on pre-compromised hosts, to use PowerShell as a Post Exploit effort.

Answer (score 0):

"The gentleman is perfectly correct" (quote: "H.M.S. Pinafore") It's not "obfusication" so much as string amendment. And just to clarify, my process starts with people accessing a batch file. This then loads the ps1 script. This loads the javascript (as a text file) amends the data, and saves it out again. The ps script then uses the Start-Process to run the browser. This is a normal HTML page that loads amended javascript via  tag. If the JS file has been correctly modified by Powershell, it runs, otherwise it stops and clears browser window.

This is the code I ended up using. Again, it won't take a programmer long to work out (they could defeat anything I'm likely to come up with) but it will 'defeat' a non-techie person.

```
$b=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String('bm9ydW5vZC5qc21heGxlbmd0aHxydW58b3V0ZmlsZQ=='))

if ($obsData -like $b.substring(10)){
$obsData[1] -replace $b.Substring(0,5),$b.$ubstring(2,1) -replace $b.Substring(2,3),$b.Substring(0,5) -replace $b.Substring(2,1),$b.Substring(2,3)|Out-File  -Encoding UTF8 "$ScriptDir\$b.Substring(5,5)"
$caps=1;
Start-Process $browserChoice "file:$ScriptDir/standard.html" -WindowStyle Maximized
}
```